# Wordpress show posts from certain category on first page

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

Id like to have on homepage on first page posts only from certain category and when user click to next page, he will see everything else.

I added this to my functions.php :

```
function my_home_category ($query) {
    if ( $query->is_home() && !($query->is_paged()) && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    $query->set( 'cat', '2');
    }
}
add_action ('pre_get_posts', 'my_home_category');
```

And it works. The only problem is, when I go to `page 2`, I see posts that would normally be at page 2 (if I didnt have this function) and not the newest posts from all categories. So if earlier there were some posts from other categories on the first page, I cant see them now anywhere.

So before the function my blog was like:

```
Page1: A, B, C, B, A <br>
Page2: B, A, A, C, B <br>
```

(A means post from category A ...)

And I would like to have it like this:

```
Page1: B, B, B, B, B <br>
Page2: A, C, A, A, A <br>
Page3: C ... <br>
```

But what happened is:

```
Page1: B, B, B, B, B <br>
Page2: B, A, A, C, B <br>
```

Can you help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

Modify your function something to:

```
function my_home_category ($query) {
    if ( $query->is_home() && !($query->is_paged()) && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    $query->set( 'cat', '2');
    }
    else{
        //Manually determine page query offset (offset + current page (minus one) x posts per page)
        $page_offset = $offset + ( ($query->query_vars['paged']-1) * $ppp );
        //Apply adjust page offset
        $query->set('offset', $page_offset );
    }
}
add_action ('pre_get_posts', 'my_home_category');
```

Comment: thanks, after little edit this works. Hovewer not quite as I wanted. What happens now is : Page1: B, B, B, B, B Page2: A, B, C, B, A (posts from category B are there again).

Comment: Also what happens is the last page of the blog disappear. There is still same number of pages on the blog, but since it is starting on page2, the last one is missing now.

Comment: Add inside `else` condition:
/*set first page ids in $do_not_duplicate */
`$query->set('post__not_in', $do_not_duplicate);`

Comment: Can you please show me whole code ? Also what to put on index.php ? Thank you